# Change automatically content of span based from number of rows from mysql using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic number of notification feed on the menu. When there is a new added data in one of my SQL table, it will change the number on the notification bar automatically, without refreshing the page.

Here's the html:

```
<li>
  <a href="categories.php">
    Categories 
    <span class="badge" id="badg"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

And here is the script that I've used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = <?php include("array.php"); ?>; /* e.g. ["1","2","3"] */
  var size = arr.length;
  document.getElementById('badg').innerHTML = size;
});
```

The number of arrays are showing, but doesn't change automatically when there is a new data. It will only change when the page are refreshed by the user.

How can I do it automatically?

Comment: you need to use ajax. You don't need to refresh the page

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use ajax in setInterval function of jquery and in response of ajax file send the updated count of notification and then just update the span by the count.

Something like this

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      //ajax content
    }, 5000); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to use "set_timeout" to check if there is a new notification data. here is a sample:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    update_notification()
});

function update_notification() {


      $.post('get_notification.php',{},
           function(e) {
                $("span#notif_number").html(e.count);
            }, 'JSON'
       );
      setTimeout(function() {
          update_notification();
        }, 2000); //displays every 3 sec
}
</script>

<div>Notifications(<span id="notif_number">0</span>)</div><br/>
```

Next you create at new page  with the name of "get_notification.php" and put the following code:

```
<?php
   //ignore this section. This is only to prove that the notification number is updating
   $count = rand(1,10);
   $data = array();
   for($a = 0; $a>=$count; $a++) {
     $_data = new stdClass();
     $_data->id = $a;
     $_data->name = "item".$a;
     array($data, $_data);
  }
  //end
  //########### YOUR CODE here#################
  //  MySQL code here
  //  $data = mysql script with data content;
  //  $count = count($data);
  echo json_encode(array("data"=> $data, "count"=>$count));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://github.com/SeanOC/jquery.comet You are trying to do something like Gmail notification or Facebook Messenger does

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       var arr = <?php include("array.php"); ?>; /* e.g. ["1","2","3"] */
       $("#badg").text(arr.length);
    }, 5000); //displays every 5 sec
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's only gonna delay the notification number by 5 seconds. But it will not refresh every 5 seconds. I also liked the idea anyway, but I don't want it to refresh every x seconds just to show a new notification. I want it to be dynamic, that it will only load or refresh the number (not the page) when there is a new data.